# Joomla 2.5 - edit "| print |" icon label

Tags: joomla

I'm updating a Joomla 2.5 template. It's going to have the Print and Email action icons visible. The Email label is fine, but the Print label has a couple of pipe characters ("|") automagically added by the core helpers/icons.php file.

Any thoughts on how to override helpers/icons.php enough to get rid of the pipes?

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrew Spartan is right. Just use an override. Two places to do that. Go to administrator.

Extensions -> Language Manager -> Overrides

Add a new override and use the constant `JGLOBAL_ICON_SEP`. Don't enter anything for the text and save it.

Or on the command line edit /language/overrides/.override.ini

Add:

`JGLOBAL_ICON_SEP=""`

Where  is the default language you use. eg. `en-GB`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting this!  It was very helpful for me.  I have a client who insisted on using the Print button to duplicate the [File] [Print] menu command, and NOT pull up the default tmpl=component blah blah, printer friendly view.  Changing that line in my code worked like a charm.  I had to add the word "Print" though to make it look right.  This is what I added:

```
<li class="print-icon"><a href="#" onclick="window.print();return false;"><?php JText::_('JGLOBAL_PRINT') ?>Print</a></li>
```

Now the only thing I would "rather" do is NOT alter my core file.  Is there a way to add this somewhere else that will override this one?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, five minutes later I think of a solution. *facepalm*

Replace:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('icon.print_popup',  $this->item, $params); ?>
```

With:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print();return false;"><?php JText::_('JGLOBAL_PRINT') ?></a>
```

Comment: I think there is more elegant solution to this problem. 
Try not to change joomla core files- because after updating it'll be replaced with new. 
Try to find in your language folder file **en-GB.ini** (or whatever language your site is using). Find there variable `JGLOBAL_ICON_SEP="|"`. Just delete **|**, so this line will be like `JGLOBAL_ICON_SEP=""`, then upload this file back to server and update page.

Comment: If this help try to use override language options in Joomla (because standart language files will be override too, when Joomla updates. Hope I'm not confusing you with this explanations. :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Andrew - I hadn't been able to track down the JGLOBAL_ICON_SEP variable.